# Echo an input field value in a php page

Tags: javascript, php

NEW CODE FROM YOUR SUGGESTIONS (STILL NOT WORKING)
I am trying to get values from an registration form to a php page with the post method and then echo it in that page so I know it works. If it does I will try to get all the values and insert them into my user table. I dont mind the sql injection risks and that I have to clean the input for now I just want to make it work. But it doesnt, do you guys see what I do wrong? Also is it possible to instead get all the values in an array and post them so I dont have to use so many variables.

```
 form.php (another page)
<?php include_once("connect.php"); ?>
<?php include_once("getTrycksaker.php"); ?>
<?php include_once("header.php"); ?>
<!-- BUILD COLUMN SYSTEM FOR CROSSDEVICE USABILITY -->
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h3 class="title">&nbsp;Registrering Företagskonto</h3><hr>
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Ange vänligen inloggningsuppgifter samt namn och telefonnummer till företagets kontaktperson.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
    <form class="form" method="post" id="compReg">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Kontaktperson"></div><br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></span>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="E-postadress"></div><br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Telefon"></div><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Lösenord"></div><br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Upprepa Lösenordet"></div><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <br><div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">Ange vänligen företagets namn, postadress samt organisationsnummer. Avvikande leveransadresser kan registreras vid order.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Företagsnamn"></div><br>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Organisationsnummer"></div><br>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Gatuadress"></div><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postnummer"></div><br>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postort"></div><br>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-paperclip"></span></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Eventuell c/o adress"></div><br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-0 col-xs-0">
        <label class="btn btn-info btn-file">Skapa Konto &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="submitBtn" onclick="rAlert('Go')" type="submit" style="display: none;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign" ></span></label>
        <br><br><br>
    </div>
    </form>
    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-0 col-xs-0"></div>
</div>
<?php include_once("footer.php"); ?>


process.php (another page)
<?php print_r($_POST);?>
```

Comment: How you submit the form?

Comment: Is the current HTML on the PHP page or is it calling a different page

Comment: I have updated the code. I submit by a button (in the code now). It is two different pages.

Comment: So you are getting value now?

Comment: No, I dont know what to put on the php page to echo the values. Since I dont know that I dont know if I get the values.

Comment: I have tried this to. But also here I dont know how to catch it the php side...            var datastring = $("#compReg").serialize();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process.php",
                data: datastring,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    //var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); if the dataType is not specified as json uncomment this
                    // do what ever you want with the server response
                },
                
            });
            </script>

Comment: where is the end of your `<form>` tag ? is that type happened when you pasted your code here or you've forgotten it ?

Comment: My form tag is lower in the code. Didnt copy everything.

Comment: I still see nothing

Comment: That form tag no longer has an action attribute

Comment: That Solved it! THANK YOU ALL!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the values using element name.All the values are inside `$_POST` Array.Just `print_r($_POST)`.You will see all the posted values.

In `process.php`;

```
extract($_POST);
echo $name;//prints name
echo $email;//prints email
```

> The `extract()` function imports variables into the local symbol table from an array.This function uses array keys as variable names and values as variable values. For each element it will create a variable in the current symbol table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?php print_r($_POST); ?>` to check exactly what is being passed to php. 
This will show all variables passed from the form and their values.

Also worth noting that only inputs with valid name attributes will be passed by the form.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this example code will help you. run my code and use this idea in your code.

in form.php

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="process.php"> 

<input type="text" name="name[]" value="a"/>
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="b"/>
<input type="text" name="name[]" value="c"/>

<label>Skapa Konto &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input  type="submit" ></label>
```

in process.php

```
<?php
$nvals = count($_REQUEST['name']);
 // do something with $_REQUEST['name'][$i] for example
 echo 'Hello ' . $_REQUEST['name'][1] . '!'; 
?>
```

it will print that 'Hello b!'

if you want to get all values using for loop use this code.

```
<?php 
$nofval = count($_REQUEST['name']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $nofval; $i++) {
   echo 'Hello ' .$_REQUEST['name'][$i] . '!';
}  
?>
```